# Use passport-jwt on server side rendered Express/React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, passport.js

I have an universal NodeJS, Express, React/Redux app that uses react-router. It is rendered from server side on initial requests of the app and on client on subsequent requests that come from react-router.

My routes.js file:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="/main" component={Main}/>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
</Route>
```

I have a wildcard express route that matches this react-routes and sends the component markup back to the template:

```
import routes from '../routes';

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match(
        { routes, location: req.url },
        (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
            let markup;
            if (renderProps) {
                markup = renderToString(
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <RouterContext {...renderProps}/>
                    </Provider>
                );
            } else {
                markup = renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
                res.status(404);
            }

            return res.render('index', { markup });
        }
    );
});
```

Now I want to protect some of the routes intercepted by the wildcard route using passport-jwt, like the example:

```
app.get("*", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), 
(req, res) => {
    match(
        { routes, location: req.url },
            (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
                res.json("Success! You can not see this without a token");
            }
    )
});
```

How can I protect only a given route from routes.js on wildcard route?

Answer (score 1):

you can add some middleware to do this via `app.use`.
 (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use)

just be sure to call this before your wildcard handler

```
app.use("/main", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), 
function(req, res){
    res.json("Success! You can not see this without a token");
});
```

Comment: Actually I want to make selective protection on my wildcard routes while server side rendering. Do you know how can I use middleware on this case?

Comment: Let's assume (just an example) you want to protect anything behind `/admin` with your token authentication middleware. To do so you would utilize `app.use('admin', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })` before you declare your wildcard handler. Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of middleware inclusion is important.

Comment: here is a more in depth example - https://github.com/scotch-io/easy-node-authentication/blob/local/server.js